# How to traverse a high-order range in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python, we can use `range(x)` to traverse from `0` to `x-1`. But what if I want to traverse a high-order range? For example, given `(a, b)`, I want to traverse all `(x1, x2)` such that `0 <= x1 < a, 0<= x2 < b`. If the dimension is fixed, then it's easy, say it's k-dimension (in the example I gave, k is 2), then we can simply hard-code k loops to achieve it, but how about when the dimension is also a variable? Is there any elegant pythonic way to handle this?

Comment: Take a look at the `itertools` module, I'll bet it has a function to do this.

Comment: nested for loops? `for i in range(x1): for j in range(x2):...`

Comment: @BrianJoseph You can only write nested for loops when you know the number of for loops in advance. But as I mentioned, when the dimension is a variable, then you will not be able to write the for loops.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension" here? Can you show a more fleshed out code example to illustrate?

Comment: @YuGu ah I see, so the number of nested loops you would need would be variable. In that case, itertools.product is the way to like kaya's answer suggests

Comment: @Code-Apprentice kaya3's answer has addressed my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```py
from itertools import product

for x, y, z in product(range(a), range(b), range(c)):
    print( (x,y,z) )
```

With a variable number of dimensions:

```py
limits = [5, 3, 7, 6]

for v in product(*(range(n) for n in limits)):
    print(v)
```

Comment: @YuGu Note that you can also accomplish this with nested for loops. Which to use depends what you are doing with the generated tuples.

Comment: Nested `for` loops will work when the number of dimensions is not variable, but not in the variable case. Note also that if you need to `break`, it's much easier if you don't use nested loops.