# All possible combination of lists for a given list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to have all possible combinations of lists of a given size. 
Lets say for example, I have a given list K, such as `K = [3, 5, 2]`. With the following code I get what I desire. But how do I generalize this for any list of a given size, without just adding for loops?

```
assignment= []
for l in range(K[0]):
    for m in range(K[1]):
        for n in range(K[2]):
            a = [l,m,n]
            assignment.append(a)
```

Comment: For example K = [3,5,2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to traverse a high-order range in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736358/how-to-traverse-a-high-order-range-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library can often help with things like this. [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in particular, using `*` to pass it a list or iterator of ranges:

```
list(itertools.product(*(range(n) for n in K))
```

or

```
list(itertools.product(*map(range, K)))
```